# Iterating through an array of files

Tags: java, arrays, textarea, filereader

I am writing a program which displays some of my written poems into an `JTextArea` and whenever I press on `JButton` "Next" it should read another one of my poems into the `JTextArea`.

However I can only do it when I remove the `filearray` and read a single file only.

Creating an array of files and tried iterating by calling a `number++` everytime I click on next. I've also filtrated by leaving out some irrelevant code.

```
public class PoemWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private int n=0;
    BufferedReader br;
    JTextArea textAreaOne;
    FileReader file[];
}

public PoemWindow() throws IOException{
    file[0] = new FileReader("C:/Poems/Freedom.txt");
    file[1] = new FileReader("C:/Poems/Masturbation.txt");
    file[2] = new FileReader("C:/Poems/Life.txt");
    file[3] = new FileReader("C:/Poems/Loneliness.txt");
    add(textAreaOne)
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource()==nextButton) {
        while(n<=4) {   
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(file[n]);
                textAreaOne.read(br,null);
                n++;
                textAreaOne.requestFocus();
            } catch(Exception b) {
                System.out.println("This is an error"); 
            }
        }
    }
```

It works when I read a single file, but whenever I instantiate an file `[]`
it gives me an `NullPointerException` and it won't even run...

Comment: While your problem was the array initialize you also need to remember that last index in the array is one less then number of element -> so if you have array of 4 element the last index is 3 (as it starting from 0) so you while loop should be `while (n<4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It works when I read a single file, but whenever I instantiate an file
>   [] it gives me an NullPointerException and it won't even run...

Here's an example of creating the array w/ five slots (0 --> 4):

```
FileReader[] file = new FileReader[4];
```

Comment: So, putting FileReader file[];  as a field value could be the problem? Because i haven't set how many slots that should be there.

Comment: Correct.  You need to give the array an initial **size** so that you have slots available to put things into.

Comment: Ok thank you for that verification :) Will have to find an alternate way to create it.

Comment: An alternative would be to not use an array.  Use a List<> so you can simply add as many items as you want and it will grow automatically for you: `List<FileReader> files = new ArrayList<>();`  Adding might look like `files.add(new FileReader("C:/Poems/Freedom.txt"));`.  See [Java ArrayList Tutorial with Examples](https://www.callicoder.com/java-arraylist/) for some more examples.

Comment: Thanks for the code, saved me alot of headache. It's easy as a newbie to just bash your skull against the wall instead of using a sledgehammer.